# TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not str in Python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, constructor

When I try to call the constructor of the superclass in the constructor of thermo.py (files below), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/wheaterstation/scripts/wsControl.py", line 58, in <module>
controller = controller()
File "/var/wheaterstation/scripts/wsControl.py", line 21, in __init__
self.thermo = thermo("Thermometer", logger)
File "/var/wheaterstation/scripts/thermo.py", line 7, in __init__
super(name, logger).__init__()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not str
```

Ive seen that in 2.6 this error often would come up if the supperclass wouldn't extend "object". I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

wsPart.py:

```
class wsPart(object):
logger = None
name = ""
def __init__(self, name, logger):
    self.logger = logger
    self.name = name
    self.logger.writeLog(self, "created")

def getName(self):
    return self.name
```

thermo.py:

```
import os, sys
from wsPart import wsPart
class thermo:
functional = False 
file = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000833e8ff/w1_slave'
def __init__(self, name, logger):
    super(name, logger).__init__() ## this calls the wsPart constructor
    functional = True

def read(self):
    ##reads out the file mentioned in line 5 and returns it
    fileobject = open(self.file)
    filecontent = fileobject.read()
    fileobject.close()
    self.logger.writeLog(self,"Completed Meassurement")
    return filecontent
```

and the part of wsControl.py that matters:

```
class controller():

name = ""
logger = None
thermo = None
dbConnector = None

def __init__(self):
    ##THis created the controller and all the other objects
    self.name = "Controller"
    ##Create Objects
    self.logger = logger()
    self.logger.writeLog(self, "logger created")
    self.thermo = thermo("Thermometer", logger)
    self.dbConnector = dbConnector("DBConnector",logger)
```

the full code is [here](https://github.com/Jocomol/wheaterstation)

Comment: You need to pass the arguments to the method being invoked *on* super, not super itself

Comment: @jonrsharpe so you mean i have to write super.__init__(self, name, logger)?

Comment: You still need to *call* super, but that's certainly closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first had to make thermo to be a subclass of wsPart:

```
class thermo:
```

changed to

```
class thermo(wsPart):
```

Then had to change:

```
super(name, logger).__init__()
```

to:

```
super().__init__(name, logger)
```